# Do not understand Error: binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite

the following error occurs at line 13:

**sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.**

Comparing code on line 2 and code on line 13, line 2 works without out a problem and seems  identical to line 13. What am I doing wrong?
date and tag are both strings.
date is for example "2018-11" and tag is something like "fare" and in my example it is always != "None".

```
if tag != "None":
        self.c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM financial_table WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', Date) = ? AND Tag = ? ORDER BY Date ", (date, tag)) #row 2
    else:
        self.c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM financial_table WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', Date) = ? ORDER BY Date ", (date,))
    single_dates = self.c.fetchall()
    for i in single_dates:
        print (i)

    #take data in order to sum up all costs from one day
    for i in single_dates:
        print ("***",i)
        if tag != "None":
            self.c.execute("SELECT Price FROM financial_table WHERE Date = ? AND Tag = ?", (i, tag)) #line 13
        else:
            self.c.execute("SELECT Price FROM financial_table WHERE Date = ?", (i)) 
        cache = self.c.fetchall()
        print (cache)
        self.plot_overall_price.append(sum(j for j, in cache)) #save overall price for
        self.plot_date.append(i[0]) #a certain date  
        self.plot_date_days.append(i[0][8:10])
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Often when you query for a single column like you have in `single_dates` the results are returned as a list of tuples e.g., `[('date',), ('date',),...]`. Are you sure that `i` in your for loop is just a date string?

Answer (score 0):

@SuperShoot
Thanks for your help. You were right, i returned "('2018-11-10',)". I fixed my problem by changing row 13 from ...(i,... to ...(i[0],...

However, sometimes is bit of a mystery for me. When tag == "None" then line 15 for example is possible and I don't need the i[0], I can just use i. I mean this line:

```
self.c.execute("SELECT Price FROM financial_table WHERE Date = ?", (i))
```